# Ember loading state blocks location.href history updating

Tags: ember.js, state, loading

When `some.route` is waiting for `slow-model`, you can have a `some.route-loading` loading state to show some kitties while waiting.

In this case it makes sense to have `some.route-error` too, so you can show a sad face when the payload breaks things.

However, when I click on a `link-to` to `some/route`, the location href in the address bar is not updated until the loading completes successfully.

I don't know if this is by design, but I would like to be able to navigate back with the browser history on error.

In other words: Can I have the location href in the address bar update *before* rather than after the loading state appears?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: no, you can’t.

Long answer: Ember’s router doesn’t consider a transition to be complete (which is when it updates the url) until you have arrived successfully in the new route. That means if you hit the loading or error substates you haven’t get made the transition. If you want the url to change early, then you may need to override loading behavior on that route and handle it custom or create a loading route of your own where you control things more ...

Comment: Upvoted. Would you be so kind as to show a code example to one (or both) example(s)? I'm especially curious as to how "override loading behavior" would work.